# Thread stack or Thread call stack

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

What I have read from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774%28v=VS.85%29.aspx),

> Each new thread or fiber receives its own stack space consisting of both reserved and initially committed memory.

Does the word 'stack' here really mean a 'call stack' or does it mean that it gets piece of memory that is called a stack?

Comment: Note the use of stack **space**.  It is the chunk of virtual memory in which the call stack lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call stack lives on the stack. Each thread or fiber has its own private stack and that's what the topic you link to is discussing.

Answer (score 0):

That is referring to the call stack - each thread/fiber needs its own to function.  Is there a reason that you think it wouldn't be the call stack?

Comment: I was confused because I didn't read it mention anywhere or maybe because it got me the wrong idea. thanks